# Getting the height of an iframe including only the rendered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to calculate the minimum height an iframe needs to be fully displayed.

To realise this, I tried the following approach:

```
    var neededSize = $(window.document).height();

    // Get the jquery of the parent in order to resize the frame
    var par = window.parent;

    if(par != null) {
        var jq = par.jQuery;

        var frameParent = jq('#' + window.frameElement.id);
        frameParent.height(neededSize);
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that the iframe contains some hidden elements (display: none;). When I use jQuery.height() it returns the minimum height it needs including the hidden elements.

Does anyone know an approach through jquery or standard javascript to get the minimum height excluding the height the hidden divs take or should i calculate this myself? (get all the hidden fields and substract each height?)

Comment: Elements with `display: none` don't take any space in the document

Comment: Still jQuery('selector').height() seems to include them..

Comment: can you demonstrate it somehow in a jsfiddle? even a quick view of the markup could help solve it.

Comment: _Seems_? Or _does_? Review your code. It must be something else.

Comment: I created a fiddle and the probleem does indeed come from someplace else, the fiddle works perfectly. I'm closing this subject. http://jsfiddle.net/LQTeT/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in the document ready handler shorthand:

```
$(function(){
  //your code here
});
```

Documentation:

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts.

So the code will be executed after all DOM elements are rendered. And probably the height is consistent then with the hidden elements. (they are probably shown in a split second because the .css is still loading)

Comment: I do not need to resize on document ready but when an event is triggered. This event gets triggered after the document is ready.